# What are all the ways to impact your trial grade?

Tags: the-outlast-trials

In The Outlast Trials, you are given a personal grade (and a team grade) when you complete a trial.  It is a letter-grade style score (A+, A, A-, B+ etc.).  Performing certain actions can increase your grade, while other factors like taking damage decreases your grade.

What are all of the ways to both positively and negatively impact the grade you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decent [guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2979158076) on Steam here that details a lot of the actions, plus having played the game for some hours now I can recall most of these:

##### Positive Actions:

- Using throwable objects to distract enemies (glass bottles)
- Damaging enemies with throwable objects

  - Landing headshots with throwable objects (such as bricks) on enemies yields more of an impact
- Performing cooperative actions (coop jumps, doors, etc.)
- Finding the propaganda posters throughout the trials (only need to find five to get the maximum impact towards your grade)
- Using items (batteries, Rig rechargers, medicine, antidote, lockpicks, adrenaline, etc.)

  - The issue with using some of these (medicine and antidote particularly) is you need to first get hurt or lose sanity which is a negative action
- Surviving a psychosis (again, getting it in the first place is a negative action)
- Using your Rig
- Bashing doors/barricades down
- Hiding
- Reviving knocked downed teammates
- Resuscitating (with a syringe) teammates
- Saving a teammate from being executed
- Saving a teammate from a trap/attack
- Disarming traps

##### Negative Actions:

- Taking Damage
- Triggering sounds traps (broken glass on ground, hanging tin cans/baby dolls, etc.)
- Trigger normal traps (psychosis mines, exploding dolls, etc.)

  - These only count if you take damage from them
- Loosing Sanity (even if you don't get full psychosis)
- Getting knocked down (i.e. needing to be revived)
- Dying (i.e. needing to be resuscitated with a syringe)
- Abandoning your teammates (not reviving them when they are knocked down/killed)

##### No impact:

- Getting seen by an enemy and/or initiating a "chase" with them
- How long it takes you to complete a trial
- Collecting more than five posters (anything beyond five doesn't matter)